# Where can I find "drops" in Ni No Kuni?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

I need stardrops to upgrade my familiars and to win the trophy. Where can I farm these and the other drops, such as moondrops and sundrops?

Answer (score 1):

If you've encountered the beasts that will drop the items you need they will usually be listed in the "ingredient sources" in the alchemy recipe to create the larger drops.

For the stardrops I think you can find these in Perdida from the snake-like creatures Ouroboros.

Answer (score 1):

All three drops can be dropped by the monsters up on Old Smoky. You should go past the bottom and go about halfway up the mountain. There is a save-stone there that you can farm around. (The drops are a bit rare so you wont get a huge pile)